# Convert NULL to Blank TPT Fast Load

Tags: teradata

```
Insert into emp values 
(:FNAME ,.......
```

Above Sample Code from TPT works fine.
I want to convert null values in flatfile  to blank while loading

```
insert into emp values ( COALESCE(:Fname,' '),....     -- Throws ERROR
```

TPT_INFRA: TPT04046: Error: Line 193 of Job Script File 'tpscript4.txt': Adjacen
t quoted strings must be separated by the
concatenation operator: '||'.
Job script preprocessing failed.

```
insert into emp Values ( case when :Fname is null then ' ' else :Fname End,... --Throws Error
```

Teradata Parallel Transporter Version 13.10.00.02
TPT_INFRA: TPT04046: Error: Line 191 of Job Script File 'tpscript4.txt': Adjacen
t quoted strings must be separated by the
concatenation operator: '||'.
Job script preprocessing failed.
Job terminated with status 8.

When used Case when in Select oerator for fastload:

```
TO OPERATOR (UPDATE_OPERATOR[2]) 
SELECT  case when FNAME is null then ' ' else FNAME,LNAME,....
FROM OPERATOR (FILE_READER[2]);
```

ERROR:
TPT_INFRA: Syntax error at or near line 249 of Job Script File 'tpscript4.txt':
TPT_INFRA: At "SELECT" missing SEMICOL_ in Rule: Job Definition Body
Compilation failed due to errors. Execution Plan was not generated.
Job script compilation failed.
Job terminated with status 8.

Note: with out the case in select it is working fine ,

```
APPLY('insert into emp values ( COALESCE(:Fname,'' ''),....')  Worked with Mload
```

and
    SELECT CASE WHEN Fname IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE Fname END AS Fname,... FROM OPERATOR   worked with Fload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify which error is returned, i assume it's related to the single quotes. Your INSERT is probably within an APPLY('INSERT ....;') you might try two single quotes to get one quote in a string:

```
APPLY('insert into emp values ( COALESCE(:Fname,'' ''),....')
```

Or do it in the SELECT (COALESCE is not supported here):

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN Fname IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE Fname END AS Fname,
   ...
FROM OPERATOR
```

Comment: Adding single quotes : UPDATE_OPERATOR: entering Acquisition Phase
UPDATE_OPERATOR: TPT10508: RDBMS error 3618: Expression not allowed in Fast Load
 Insert, column Fname.
UPDATE_OPERATOR: disconnecting sessions

Comment: "Expression not allowed in Fast Load Insert" = you can't use expressions in the INSERT within the FastLoad protocol. Switch to the UPDATE operator instead or do it in the SELECT as shown above.

Comment: Select case when : Teradata Parallel Transporter Version 13.10.00.02
TPT_INFRA: Syntax error at or near line 249 of Job Script File 'tpscript4.txt':
TPT_INFRA: At "SELECT" missing SEMICOL_ in Rule: Job Definition Body
Compilation failed due to errors. Execution Plan was not generated.

Comment: dnoeth , single quote works for Mload . Case is not working for Fload ?

Comment: When you use the CASE in the OPERATOR Select it should work, i just forgot the alias (edited). If you still get an error you should post the relevant parts of the job definition. --- I just noticed you don't have an END in your CASE, it should be `SELECT  case when FNAME is null then ' ' else FNAME END as FName,LNAME`